# Invalid Registry while updating windows 7 to windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, windows-registry, operating-systems

I was updating my pc from windows 7 to windows 10 after downloading and installing windows 10 then it was downloading updates like in 25%-28% it showed a error saying many things but I remembered one line it sayed **Invalid registry** *(i was doing it yesterday night)* and it suddenly showed **"undoing changes made to your computer"** and went back to windows 7.

Pls Help! my pc specs-

Intel pentium g2010 2.80ghz

4gb ram

500gb storage (upto 263gb free)

No gragics card

os-

Windows 7 Ultimate